# LeetCode's "House Robber" problem path -- can't print path

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I have solved [LeetCode's "House Robber" problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/house-robber/), but I'm unable to print the path. I've tried few tricks using a list, but I always get the wrong answer. How do I remember the previous decision and remove the element and add the element to list to have the house list?

```
public static int rob(int[] nums) {
    if (nums == null || nums.length == 0)
        return 0;

    if (nums.length == 1)
        return nums[0];

    int[] dp = new int[nums.length];
    dp[0] = nums[0];
    dp[1] = Math.max(nums[0], nums[1]);

    for (int i = 2; i < nums.length; i++) {
        dp[i] = Math.max(dp[i - 2] + nums[i], dp[i - 1]);
    }

    return dp[nums.length - 1];
}
```

Comment: [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Give us a driver program and show the actual and desired outputs.

Comment: You only need two immediate previous results, one including the previous term and other excluding the previous term ... from these previous results you can now compute the new results of inclusion and exclusion of  the current term and extend this procedure till end ... tell me if you want the code

Answer (score 1):

The original problem is [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/house-robber/description/)

You can use an array `path[]` to memorize previous step. In this case, `path[i]` denotes the index from which we reach `i`.

In the code below, `res` stores the final path of the robber (1-based index). Take `nums = [3,6,2,4,5]` as an example. The `path[]` will be `[-2147483648,-2147483648,0,2,2,3]`. And then we backtrack to find the path, which will be `[2,5]`. So the robber will rob the 2nd and 5th house and get `6+5=11`.

```
public void rob(int[] nums) {
    if (nums == null || nums.length == 0) return;
    int[] dp = new int[nums.length + 1];
    int[] path = new int[nums.length + 1];
    dp[0] = 0;
    dp[1] = nums[0];
    Arrays.fill(path, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    for (int i = 2; i <= nums.length; i++) {
        if (dp[i - 2] + nums[i - 1] > dp[i - 1]) {
            path[i] = i - 2;
            dp[i] = dp[i - 2] + nums[i - 1];
        } else {
            path[i] = i - 1;
            dp[i] = dp[i - 1];
        }
    }

    LinkedList<Integer> res = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    int i = nums.length;
    while (i > 0) {
        if (path[i] == i - 1) {
            i--;
        } else {
            res.addFirst(i);
            i = path[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @wsteg. I did something similar. Mine also works, Your suggestion will also work and I will test it out. 
One solution that I still could not make work was whereby the ``List`` is populated along with the same loop as``dp`` array. I think that will require removing element also from the list. That was a solution where I have still been struggling. Any thoughts on that too?